# find data in an a row that contains a lot of data mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I've a mysql table (price) that is like this one:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          ID      DATA                       INFO                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1       2015-05-29     (3.50-22-22),(3.50-21-22),(3.50-20-22) |
|          2       2015-05-30     (4.50-22-22),(1.50-11-22),(3.00-10-02) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now i'd like to do a query that find only the values that contains the string "-22-22)" and in particular I'd like to obtain only 2 values (3.50-22-22) and (4.50-22-22)

So I do a (partial) query like this

```
string="-22-22)"

$sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE  info like '%$string%'";
$array = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($array)){
$info = $rows['info'];
$result= explode(",", $info);
```

How can continue this query to obtain mine result?

Comment: Stop what you're trying to do, and normalize your database properly

Comment: I second that. I have lost count of how many times I have seen comma-separated values in database columns. Convert the INFO column to another table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to accomplish this, you can pass in your $result and write a custom callback to filter what you need. But this depends a little on your final needs, for instance if you can always drop the first key, then just unset that, unset($results[0]), and then return only the remaining values ([array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php))

Per @cicciopasticcio 's comment.

You can try something like this:

```
return array_filter($results, function($item) use ($string) {
    return ( strpos($item, $string) !== false );
});
```

Here is the code that would work, i tested this on the command line and it $finalResults holds the two expected results.

```
$string="22-22";
$finalResults = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE  info like '%$string%'";
$array = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($array)){
    $info = $rows['info'];
    $result = explode(",", $info);
    $search = array_filter($results, function($item) use ($string) {
        return ( strpos($item, $string) !== false );
    });
    if (!empty($search[0])){
        $finalResults[] = $search[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi tobias thanks for you reply...No I dont know if it will be alway the firste ore second or etc result...it depends on $string value...could you give me an example about what you say to me?

Comment: Hi Tobias...sorry I dont understand your example...could you write all the code?The final result I need is only (3.50-22-22) and (4.50-22-22). Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added it for you the way i know it works, not very pretty as it stands,  but it shows the intend.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE  info like '%$string%'";
```

With this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE  info REGEXP('$string')";
```

REGEXP will find the value in your current stored info in your table.

Else you can also try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE  info IN('$string')";
```

OR

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(info, '$string')";
```